# VueJS: is there any performance benefit for using vue refs instead of css id to control a div element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I tried to find a comparison or a reason to why Vue has refs to control an element instead of using classic css ids to control some element like a div for example, can someone explain the difference? is there a performance advantage for refs?

```
<div ref="hello">
</div>

<div id="hello">
</div>
```

Update:

*I am not asking about this for opinion based answers or just styles, I am searching for any clue regarding performance difference between the 2 approaches*

Answer (score 2):

The benefits of `ref` that i see :

- The syntax is Vue friendly `this.$refs.hello`
- They could be used to reference component `<HelloWorld ref="hello" />` which could be used in parent to run some child component logic
- The `ref` could be used in `v-for` loop to return array of elements

> When used on elements/components with `v-for`, the registered reference will be an Array containing DOM nodes or component instances

- They are not exposed outside the Vue app context.